# Very poor rendering quality with my Macbook Thunderbolt 27''

Tags: macbook-pro, display, color, thunderbolt-display

I have a MacBook Pro (2015) with an external Monitor Mac Thunderbolt (2013).

I've NEVER had a beautiful image on my external monitor, no matter the OS X version was.
At work, I'm working with an iMac, and despite being similar in specifications, the image is far better and cleaner than my monitor.

I use the default calibration and default resolution from the general settings.

I get a kind of yellow opacity, and the font is blurry.

Has anyone already experienced it and managed to solve it?

Considering the price it costed, I expect a great screen quality.

Comment: Have you tested the monitor with another Mac yet?

Comment: I have two Macbook Pro (2012 and 2015), and with both the external monitor rendering isn't good enough.

Comment: Then it's likely that some component of the monitor is just faulty.  :(

Comment: Another possibility (if you've used the same cable and/or adapter with both MBPs) is a faulty cable and/or adapter.